# Power Automate: JSON Array has a Variable within Variable want to separate the the two for Dynamic Content

Tags: json, power-automate

I have A JSON output from an API.

It has lots of info and Also has a Variable in a Variable that i can't seem to decode.

```
[
  {
    "id": "1029384",
    "employeeId": "101390",
    "status": {
      "lastChanged": "2024-01-08",
      "lastChangedByUserId": "763051",
      "status": "approved"
    },
    "name": "Lelouch Vi Britania",
    "start": "2024-01-10",
    "end": "2024-01-12",
    "created": "2024-01-05",
    "type": {
      "id": "84",
      "name": "Vacation",
      "icon": "time-off-calendar"
    },
    "amount": {
      "unit": "days",
      "amount": "3"
    },
    "actions": {
      "view": true,
      "edit": false,
      "cancel": false,
      "approve": false,
      "deny": false,
      "bypass": false
    },
    "dates": {
      "2024-01-10": "1",
      "2024-01-11": "1",
      "2024-01-12": "1"
    },
    "notes": {
      "employee": "You Emperor Comands You to Take Vacation"
    }
  },
```

The "Dates" Variable

```
"dates": {
      "2024-01-10": "1",
      "2024-01-11": "1",
      "2024-01-12": "1"
```

I want to Separate the "Date" and the "amount"

I have Tried the following

```
item()['dates']
```

and Variations on a theme but can't seem to get the out put to look like this

Comment: Unclear what you are asking/needing. Can you provide an example of what you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Reflection type operations in PowerAutomate is fairly lacking, however, I strongly suggest you look at investing in the **Advanced Data Operations** connector.

There's an operation called `Json Properties to Name Value Pair Array` which will turn each property into an object array which then allows you to loop over or filter the relevant data out.

I took the dataset you provided and extracted the `dates` object out using an expression which then fed the data to the ADO operation, it converted this ...

```
{
  "2024-01-10": "1",
  "2024-01-11": "1",
  "2024-01-12": "1"
}
```

... to this ...

```
[
  {
    "propertyName": "2024-01-10",
    "propertyType": "String",
    "propertyValue": "1"
  },
  {
    "propertyName": "2024-01-11",
    "propertyType": "String",
    "propertyValue": "1"
  },
  {
    "propertyName": "2024-01-12",
    "propertyType": "String",
    "propertyValue": "1"
  }
]
```

It makes life a lot easier.

https://statesolutions.com.au/json-properties-to-name-value-pair-array/

[image: Result]